# How to unit test exception filter in web API ASP.Net core. Dont want to mock the onException method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

How to unit test exception filter in web API ASP.Net core. Don't want to mock the onException method. I have mocked ControllerContext like below in my unit tests. Class libraries which are called from the Web API throw custom exceptions which are caught by exception filters and I want to unit test that. Today I get "Value does not fall within the expected range" error.

```
    public static ControllerContext GetMockControllerContext(
        this Controller controller,
        RouteData routeData)
    {

        var actionContext = new ActionContext
        {
            HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
            {
                User = controller.GetMockUserContext()
            },
            RouteData = routeData,
            ActionDescriptor = new ControllerActionDescriptor()
        };
        return new ControllerContext(actionContext);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I would write an integration test using TestServer as covered in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing#integration-testing). It will run about as fast as an actual unit test but will be much more valuable as it will demonstrate your filter working within the actual MVC context/pipeline.

Comment: In this documentation its only written you should test filters in isolation.

Comment: Integration tests are covered here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0